# Filling data automatically with fill handle

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data sheet and I want to fill data using fill handle in Excel because there are so many repetitive works to do, but I can't customize its pattern. 
For example I want to have cells with the following formulas:

```
=REVENUES!C9*REVENUES!E9 | =REVENUES!C9*REVENUES!F9 | =REVENUES!C9*REVENUES!G9 | ...
```

[image]

But when I use fill handle, "C9" cell will also be changed!
What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want C9 to be fixed, you need to change it to an absolute reference by using $ signs:

```
=REVENUES!$C$9*REVENUES!E9
```

Then you can use autofill, and C9 will stay but E9 will change.

See e.g. here for absolute vs. relative references:
http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/cell-references.html

Comment: Wow! very interesting! TNX.